# Javascript: Is it possible to find out if the visitor used IP-Address or Domain Name?

Tags: javascript, dns, ip

I'm interested in knowing if a visitor to my site used http://ip-address or http://domain-name.  Is this possible with javascript?

Comment: In JS, you can check the `location` object. If the site didn’t redirect to the domain name version, then the host of the current location will still be an IP address. Why do you need this, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, DNS servers simply look up the IP address for a domain name and forward the request to that address. The web server never sees what the user entered into the address bar, only the path, query, and fragment.

Comment: "No, DNS servers simply look up the IP address for a domain name and forward the request to that address." No. A browser uses the OS or direct ways like with DOH to resolve names and then connect. The DNS servers do not "forward" requests.

Comment: "The web server never sees what the user entered into the address bar" That is completely untrue. Do you know about the HTTTP `host` header? Its value will be what the user entered on the address bar, name or IP. This is needed otherwise name-based virtualhosting wouldn't be possible. Same for SNI in TLS handshake in case of name-based virtualhosting of HTTPS website.